# How to clip an SVG to the inside of the stroke?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to clip an SVG to eliminate the stroke from two sides: specifically, clipping this parallelogram using the red rectangle to get the result on the right.

[image]

(The shape is constant but size and stroke may be variable so I'm trying to avoid doing maths with the stroke width directly)

I've read a lot of tutorials about CSS clipping, which usually have some trivial example using a polygon clipping path, and then descend into snippets of BNF grammar describing how geometry-box can be used without any meaningful examples.

[This page](https://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-css-clip-path-property/) on clip paths in the "Clipping Elements With geometry-box Values" section say a clipping path can specify a geometry box which defines what the percentages are relative to, one of the options being fill-box.

> .clip-me {   clip-path: polygon(10% 20%, 20% 30%, 50% 80%) margin-box;
>   margin: 10%; }
>
> In case of SVG elements, [geometry-box] can be fill-box, stroke-box and view-box. The value view-box will use the nearest SVG
>   viewport as a reference box if no view-box is specified.

I interpreted this as meaning replacing margin-box with fill-box would set the polygon relative to the blue rectangle in my example (the bounding box of the path fill), so I could make a polygon that's just a 100% width, >100% height rectangle.  In practise, when I set the style to `"clip-path: polygon(0% -30%, 0% 130%, 100% 130%, 100% -30%) fill-box"` it doesn't clip at all, but the equivalent without specifying a geometry-box clips to the midline of the stroke.

Is there a way to set a clipping path relative to the bounding box of the SVG path's fill, so I can clip it to the red box, or some other way to remove these side strokes and keep the fill?

---

My minimal reproducible example:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <svg width="960" height="960">
      <g stroke-width="15" stroke="#000">
        <path d="M20 35 l 160 -20 l 0 140 l -160 20 l 0 -140 z" fill="#ccc" 
              style="clip-path: polygon(0% -30%, 0% 130%, 100% 130%, 100% -30%);" >
        </path>
      </g>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [chriskirknielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61279328/1045510)'s answer says, by default SVG strokes are drawn centered around the path. Instead of duplicating the path, you can use the [`paint-order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/paint-order) attribute to make the fill be drawn above the stroke, so that the inner part of the stroke is not visible.

Note that to maintain the visual width of the stroke, you'll need to double its width, because effectively half of it is covered by the fill.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <svg width="960" height="960">
      <g stroke-width="30" stroke="#000">
        <path d="M20 35 l 160 -20 l 0 140 l -160 20 l 0 -140 z" fill="#ccc" 
              style="clip-path: polygon(0% -30%, 0% 130%, 100% 130%, 100% -30%); paint-order: stroke;" >
        </path>
      </g>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I learn about that property every month, and forget… This is indeed better!

Comment: Huh - that does achieve what I wanted quite effectively.  Out of interest, is what I'm trying to do even possible, or am I misunderstanding what the tutorials are telling me about fill-box?

Answer (score 1):

Strokes in SVG "spill" on both sides of the path, so for example, a `10px` stroke will have `5px` on the outside, and `5px` on the inside (covering the fill area), which looks like is what is happening in your example. You can place your `clip-path` on the group, and duplicate your path: below: the stroke; above: the fill.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <svg width="960" height="960">
      <g style="clip-path: polygon(0% -30%, 0% 130%, 100% 130%, 100% -30%);">
        <path d="M20 35 l 160 -20 l 0 140 l -160 20 l 0 -140 z" stroke-width="15" stroke="#000"/>
        <path d="M20 35 l 160 -20 l 0 140 l -160 20 l 0 -140 z" fill="#ccc"/>
        </path>
      </g>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```